# Normal view Android Notification with Buttons

Tags: android, android-notifications

I read that we can add buttons to the Big view of notifications that is available from 4.1. I want the same layout with buttons in 4.0. I want to know if I use custom view for notification containing the buttons, Will that work in 4.0 ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notifications before 4.1 were limited which is why Big View notifications were introduced in 4.1

It isn't possible to have custom views before 4.1 unfortunately

One of the reasons for this is the height of the notification, its is limited so it doesn't fill up the screen.